# Multiple Inputs for one "cin"

Tags: c++

My assignment calls for an output that looks similiar to ths:

Sample output: 
Enter product type and quantity sold (enter Z to stop):  A 2

Total sales of product A = $5.97

The letter represents the price of the object and the number following represents the quantity of the object. So how would i get my cin to get both the object and the quantity?
I currently have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    double ProfitA, ProfitB, ProfitC;
    double TotalA = 0;
    char type;
    int quant; 
    ProfitA = (1.99) * quant;
    ProfitB = (2.99) * quant;
    ProfitC = (3.99) * quant;

    cout << "Enter product type and quantity sold (enter -1 to stop)\n\n";
    cin >> type >> quant;
    switch (type)
    {
    case 'A':cout << "Total sales of product A =" << ProfitA << "\n";
        break;
    case 'B':cout << "Total sales of product B =" << ProfitB << "\n";
        break;
    case 'C':cout << "Total sales of product C =" << ProfitC << "\n";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Don't calculate the profit until after you get the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

While running the program, Type enter after each input.
then before running the program, edit your code to have the profit calculation after the inputs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

as @Pete Becker pointed out, you are attempting to calculate the profits before your user has entered in a quantity.

change your code to this:

```
char type;
int quant; 

cout << "Enter product type and quantity sold (enter -1 to stop)\n\n";
cin >> type >> quant;

ProfitA = (1.99) * quant;
ProfitB = (2.99) * quant;
ProfitC = (3.99) * quant;
```